# When try to flush cache Magento admin get log out automatically and css files not found

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-panel, multi-website

I am getting a strange error in my Magento admin panel. Whenever I try to hit **flush cache** button, Magento admin gets logout and all CSS removed. It looks like this:

[image]

Then if I refresh it, I get normal Login screen of Admin panel. After I login again, all my websites (I am using multi-website) gone. So to achieve my websites again I have to save my main website from here:

[image]

After I hit **save** button, admin panel again gets logout and I get this window:

[image]

When I login again, all websites come back again and all goes fine. But If I again try to flush the cache, the above process again follows.

Please help me urgently.

Thanks

Comment: remove var/cache folder and check again.